# How is it that I overlapping MLflow runs when I always made sure to close/end them?

Tags: mlflow

I'm trying to start runs using MLflow via a context manager like this:

```
with mlflow.start_run(MLFLOW_RUN_NAME):
    stuff
```

However, ever since I started to use MLflow I keep getting the exception:

```
Exception: Run with UUID e41337547c9048b1a47a853888990e2e is already active.
To start a new run, first end the current run with mlflow.end_run().
To start a nested run, call start_run with nested=True
```

When I put `mlflow.end_run()` before the context manager, that actually seems to get it to work. What I'm finding weird is that:

1. Shouldn't the context manager run `mlflow.end_run()` automatically?
2. My MLflow run names are named according to time (down to the second) and so there's no way that their names are overlapping. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please try to distil a minimal not working example :-)
Also note that `start_run` should be used differently, the name is a keyword argument in recent MLFlow versions https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html?highlight=start_run#mlflow.start_run